# Why does sleep() block std::ostream

Tags: c++, concurrency, sleep, iostream

Given the following:

```
const char opn[8] = { 0x16, 'O', 'P', 'N', 0x17, 0xa8, 0xa9, '\0' };
std::cout << opn;
sleep(5);
```

The string will only be written to `cout` after five seconds. The expected behavior would be for it to print the message to `cout`, and then wait for seconds.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I predict the outcome would change if you write `cout.flush()` before sleeping

Comment: First, where is your \0 ? Second, line buffering may be a factor, but first get rid of the UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::cout` is buffered by default, so the message won't be printed immediately but only when `std::cout`'s buffer is flushed, i.e., when the program terminates.

Use

```
std::cout << opn << std::flush;
```

As @RemyLebeau stated in the comments to this answer, `<< std::endl` is equivalent to `<< '\n' << std::flush;` and also flushes the buffer.

---

Furthermore, you are missing the trailing null byte, so your program is undefined anyway as of now.

Comment: `std::cout << opn << std::endl` will also flush the buffer (after outputting a newline).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alright, but how does this help the OP? If he wanted a trailing newline he would've stated that I think.

Comment: Just stating an extra fact about flushing.  Not everyone understands that `std::endl` performs a flush, many people think it is just an alias for `'\n'` and use them interchangably.

Answer (score 7):

Output is normally buffered, so it won't come out until the buffer is full or the file is closed. You need to manually [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) the output; e.g.:

```
std::cout << i << " " << std::flush;
```

If you wanted a line break to be inserted, you could use `std::endl`, which both inserts a line break *and* flushes the stream:

```
std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`cout` is buffered so it is saving the in-between things you are printing and printing them all at once when it flushes.

You can either add `<< std::endl;` to the line that prints `i` or otherwise flush the buffer manually.